# context manager sqlalchemy close connection on fetchone

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, contextmanager

I have a specific use-case where:

1. I am using SQLAlchemy Core
2. I only ever want to `.fetchone()` from a `ResultsProxy`
3. Will context manager autoclose my connection or will I have to close it manually?:

::

```
with engine.connect() as sqla_conn:
    a_result_dict = dict(sqla_conn.execute(a_sqlalchemy_selectable).fetchone())

# will sqla_conn be closed after __exit__? 
# or will it be kept open because the cursor may still have available rows to fetch?
```

Answer (score 0):

once the program is out of the 'with' scope, the context manager will close the connexion , for further infos refer to [link](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/)